# How can I access the data for the snake object sent through JSON in my params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

Using javascript, I make a fetch post.

```
const game = {name: this.player, snake: this.snake, score: this.score, apple: this.apple, skull: this.skull, completed: this.completed}
        return fetch("http://localhost:3000/games", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(game)
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => Game.appendHighScores(json));
```

I access the data via params on the Ruby on Rails end. The data for `params[:snake][:body]` are supposed to look like `"body"=>[{"x"=>16, "y"=>15}, {"x"=>16, "y"=>14}, {"x"=>16, "y"=>15}]}`, yet when I type them into the command line, they look like this:

`[<ActionController::Parameters {"x"=>16, "y"=>15} permitted: false>, <ActionController::Parameters {"x"=>16, "y"=>14} permitted: false>, <ActionController::Parameters {"x"=>16, "y"=>15} permitted: false>]`

It is accessible via indexing, but I get everything along with the data I'm looking for.

I was hoping it would look like the original params when I typed it in

`<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Don", "snake"=>{"x"=>16, "y"=>15, "direction"=>"down", "speed"=>0, "directions"=>{"left"=>{"x"=>-1, "y"=>0}, "up"=>{"x"=>0, "y"=>-1}, "right"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>0}, "down"=>{"x"=>0, "y"=>1}}, "image"=>{}, "body"=>[{"x"=>16, "y"=>15}, {"x"=>16, "y"=>14}, {"x"=>16, "y"=>15}]}, "score"=>0, "apple"=>{"image"=>{}, "x"=>2, "y"=>10}, "skull"=>{"image"=>{}, "x"=>12, "y"=>12}, "completed"=>true, "controller"=>"games", "action"=>"create", "game"=>{"score"=>0, "skull"=>{"image"=>{}, "x"=>12, "y"=>12}, "apple"=>{"image"=>{}, "x"=>2, "y"=>10}, "completed"=>true}} permitted: false>`

Anyway to get the params as an array without it looking so messy with `ActionController::Parameters` inside of the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason everything is wrapped inside `ActionController::Parameters` is for your security (mass assignment in particular). You should never trust data send from the internet. This class allows you to permit/whitelist what properties you trust and filter out everything that you don't trust.

```
snake_params = params.require(:snake).permit(body: [:x, :y])
```

You can then convert this into a hash with a simple [`to_h`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h) call, which will drill down into all other nested parameters that are also permitted.

```
snake_data = snake_params.to_h
#=> { "body" => [{"x"=>16, "y"=>15}, {"x"=>16, "y"=>14}, {"x"=>16, "y"=>15}] }
```

If you'd like to include other attributes as well you can add them to the `permit` list.

```
.permit(:direction, :speed, directions: {left: [:x, :y], up: [:x, :y], ...}, body: [:x, :y])
```

For more info about `permit` I suggest checking out the guide [Action Controller Overview - 4.5 Strong Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

If you don't care about permitting certain parameters you can permit everything with [`permit!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21).

Note that you don't have to permit parameters if you extract the values directly. The code below would work perfectly fine without permitting anything.

```
body = params[:snake][:body]
body.each |body_part|
  x = body_part[:x]
  y = body_part[:y]
  // do stuff with x and y
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Rails utilize "strong parameters" you have to list and allow the parameters in the controller you want to use.

Since you have a list of parameters with dynamic keys the easiest way to do, while you are in development mode is to permit them like this:

```rb
# in your controller

def game_params
  params.require(:game).tap do |permitted|
    permitted[:name] = params[:name].permit!
    permitted[:snake] = params[:snake].permit!
    permitted[:apple] = params[:apple].permit!
    permitted[:skull] = params[:skull].permit!
    permitted[:completed] = params[:completed].permit!
  end
end
```

and then you will be able to access your params:

```rb
game_params[:snake][:body]
```

In production tho, I will encourage you to whitelist all of the keys, for example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032312/544113).