# How can I parse these hashes turned string, from my Ruby on Rails API so that it's accessible as an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

The data is stored as an array of objects wrapped in a string that looks like this

```
["{\"x\"=>15, \"y\"=>7}", "{\"x\"=>14, \"y\"=>7}", "{\"x\"=>13, \"y\"=>7}", "{\"x\"=>13, \"y\"=>6}", "{\"x\"=>13, \"y\"=>5}", "{\"x\"=>13, \"y\"=>4}", "{\"x\"=>13, \"y\"=>3}", "{\"x\"=>12, \"y\"=>3}", "{\"x\"=>11, \"y\"=>3}"]
```

The reason it is stored that way is because when I was storing the data from a json, I had to convert what was wrapped in Action Parameters to a hash.

I took a look at [How to convert a ruby hash object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183786/how-to-convert-a-ruby-hash-object-to-json) and [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript), and my answer is not addressed.

First, the problem is that it would seem JSON does not parse anything wrapped in double quotations, nor with rocket hash notation, and so I am not able to convert to convert `"{"x"=>15, "y"=>7}"` to `{"x"=>15, "y"=>7}`.

Perhaps, I have to serialize the object, see where I get my data from here: [How can I access the data for the snake object sent through JSON in my params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199983/how-can-i-access-the-data-for-the-snake-object-sent-through-json-in-my-params/62204892#62204892)

Any ideas on what the right approach would be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a String object into a Hash object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object)

Comment: @SebastianPalma, no. I'm not looking to convert my string into a hash object, but rather to JSON.

Comment: That's what the given answer does, and you accepted it.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, you're right. At first glance I thought it solved my problem, but I needed to take it one step further. I wrote my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following radiantshaw's lead, using either

`eval("{\"x\"=>15, \"y\"=>7}")`

or

`JSON.parse("{\"x\"=>15, \"y\"=>7}".gsub('=>', ':'))`

I got the following: `{"x"=>15, "y"=>7}`, which is a Ruby object. However in order to convert this to a Javascript object, I also needed to convert it to json.

So by taking it one step further, I am able to parse it into json like so:

Put `require 'json'` in the .rb file, and then do `{"x"=>15, "y"=>7}.to_json` which will result in

`"{\"x\":15,\"y\":7}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not able to convert to JSON because hash rocket is not a proper JSON syntax. Hash rocket is purely Ruby syntax.

What that means is that you somehow managed to take a `Hash` and convert it to a `String`. So the converted string is actually Ruby code and not JSON.

You could do...

```rb
eval("{\"x\"=>15, \"y\"=>7}")
```

... and it will return a Ruby `Hash`.

Or if you don't want to use `eval` due to security reasons, you can do...

```rb
JSON.parse("{\"x\"=>15, \"y\"=>7}".gsub('=>', ':'))
```